# Infinite loop of #include prevents build of code

Tags: c, gtk, header-files

I'm using c and gtk + 3 to create a GUI. I don't know if it's the right way to do it but with when I want to clear the window and build another page of my app I put everything in a box that I destroy when the "new page" function is called. I create a menu that goes to a functionality of my app, a roll of dice, and I want a button that come back to the menu from that page who role the dice, but with my programs I can't because that creates an infinite loop of #include, Here's my code:

The "Home Page":

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gmodule.h>
#include "De.h"

void HomePage(GSList *lAbsolute)
{
    GtkWidget *pWindow;
    GtkWidget *pBoiteTotal;
    GtkWidget *pBoiteHome;
    GtkWidget *pDeBtn;
    GtkWidget *pFicheBtn;

    pWindow = (GtkWidget*) g_slist_nth_data(lAbsolute, 0);
    pBoiteTotal = (GtkWidget*) g_slist_nth_data(lAbsolute, 1);

    gtk_widget_destroy (pBoiteTotal);

    pBoiteHome = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 50);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pWindow), pBoiteHome);
    lAbsolute = g_slist_append(lAbsolute,(GtkWidget*) pBoiteHome);

    pDeBtn = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Lancer de de");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(pBoiteHome), pDeBtn, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    pFicheBtn = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Fiche des joueurs");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(pBoiteHome), pFicheBtn, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    gtk_widget_show_all(pWindow);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pDeBtn), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(Draw), lAbsolute);

}
```

The home page.h :

```
#include "homepage.c"

void HomePage(GSList *lAbsolute)
```

The Draw function which is in the De.c (I disable the ReturnHomePage func to stop the loop)

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gmodule.h>
#include "Lancer.h"
//#include "ReturnHomePage.h"

void Draw(GtkWidget *pDrawBtn, GSList *lAbsolute)
{
    GtkWidget *pWindow;
    GtkWidget *pImage;
    GtkWidget *pBoiteHome;
    GtkWidget *pBoiteDe;
    GtkWidget *pBoiteReturnBtn;
    GtkWidget *pReturnBtn;
    GtkWidget *pImageReturnBtn;


    pWindow = (GtkWidget*) g_slist_nth_data(lAbsolute, 0);
    pBoiteHome = (GtkWidget*) g_slist_nth_data(lAbsolute, 6);

    gtk_widget_destroy (pBoiteHome);

    pBoiteDe = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pWindow), pBoiteDe);

    pBoiteReturnBtn = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pBoiteDe), pBoiteReturnBtn);

    pImageReturnBtn = gtk_image_new();
    gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(pImageReturnBtn), "img/btn/returnbtn.png");

    pReturnBtn = gtk_button_new_with_label(NULL);
    gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(pReturnBtn), pImageReturnBtn);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(pBoiteReturnBtn), pReturnBtn, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    pImage = gtk_image_new();
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(pBoiteDe), pImage, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
 
    pDrawBtn = gtk_button_new_with_label("Lancer");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(pBoiteDe), pDrawBtn, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
 

    gtk_widget_show_all(pWindow);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pDrawBtn), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(Lancer),(GtkWidget*) pImage);
    //g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pReturnBtn), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(ReturnHomePage), lAbsolute);
    
}
```

The De.h :

```
#include "De.c"

void Draw(GtkWidget *pDrawBtn, GSList *lAbsolute);
```

And the returnhomepage.c with is .h

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gmodule.h>
#include "HomePage.h"


void ReturnHomePage(GtkWidget *pReturnBtn, GSList *lAbsolute)
{
    HomePage(lAbsolute);
}

#include "ReturnHomePage.c"

void ReturnHomePage(GtkWidget *pReturnBtn, GSList *lAbsolute);
```

I just want a way to come back from the draw function to the Homepage function because mine does not work.

Comment: Is all of this content really just to say that you have a header loop?

Comment: Is there *really* any reason why you include C files? And even worse, why you include C files within headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*but with my programs i can't because that create an infinite loop of #include*

In each of your header files, make sure to use a [header guard](https://riptutorial.com/c/example/7662/header-include-guards) to prevent content of file from being referenced more than once...

> some_header.h

```
//very top of file
#ifndef SOME_HEADER_H
#define SOME_HEADER_H

// header content here

//very bottom of file
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this: The rule of thumb is to never, ever `#include` a `.c` file. That's not what the include mechanism is meant for, and things will get confusing quickly.